# RegEx to Swap Dates Around

Tags: regex, bash

I have a number of files that include a date in the name, in the format:

```
filename - day month year (e.g. myfile - 22 August 2017)
```

What I'd like to do is to have it in the format:

```
filename - yearmonthday (e.g. myfile - 20170822)
```

Looking for a way to do this in bash.

Many thanks - Colin

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Fair point, thanks Cyrus.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash parameter expansion and (GNU?) date

```
$ f="myfile - 22 August 2017"
$ d=${f##* - }; echo "$d"
22 August 2017
$ new_d=$(date -d "$d" "+%Y%m%d")
$ echo mv "$f" "${f/%$d/$new_d}"
mv myfile - 22 August 2017 myfile - 20170822
```

Comment: I recommend using `${f/%$d/$new_d}` in the unlikely event of the filename being for example: `22 August 2017 something - 22 August 2017`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the perl rename utility, you can do (not very elegant, but it works!):

```
rename  'my %m=(Jan=>"01",Feb=>"02",Mar=>"03",Apr=>"04",May=>"05",Jun=>"06",Jul=>"07",Aug=>"08",Sep=>"09",Oct=>"10",Nov=>"11",Dec=>"12",);s/^(.+? - )(\d+) ([a-z]{3})[a-z]* (\d+)$/$1.$4.$m{$3}.$2/ie' *
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `myfile` never contains spaces, try this:

```
while read f minus day month year ; do 
    case a$month in
        (aJan*) nm=01 ;;
        (aFeb*) nm=02 ;;
        (aMar*) nm=03 ;;
        (aApr*) nm=04 ;;
        (aMay*) nm=05 ;;
        (aJun*) nm=06 ;;
        (aJul*) nm=07 ;;
        (aAug*) nm=08 ;;
        (aSep*) nm=09 ;;
        (aOct*) nm=10 ;;
        (aNov*) nm=11 ;;
        (aDec*) nm=12 ;;
    esac; 
    echo "$f - $year$nm$day" 
    # or
    mv "$f - $day $mont $year" "$f - $year$nm$day"
 done
```

Or with as regex (for use with `sed`):

```
s/January/01/
s/February/02/
s/March/03/
s/April/04/
s/May/05/
s/June/06/
s/July/07/
s/August/08/
s/September/09/
s/October/10/
s/November/11/
s/December/12/
s/\(.* -\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\1 \4\3\2/
```